# How to request to the server to send more data

Tags: meteor, minimongo

```
Meteor.publish("items", (limit) => {
  return items.find({}, {limit: limit || 15});
})

renderMoreItems(){
 const newRenderedItems = items.find(this.state.options, {
   skip: this.state.rendered,
   sort: {dateCreated: -1}
 }).fetch();
}
```

I am pretty sure my problem is trying to retrieve data when the server has only sent the 15.  So I am trying to find a way to request for the server to send another 15 items in the collection and skip the past 15.

How do I request more data from the server without calling `Meteor.subscribe` again.  Ive read somewhere that it is really slow and is not recommended.  Previously I had the server sending over all the data and then it filtered it on the client side, and it was very slow.

Answer (score 0):

`skip` can be used for this purpose.

The query can look like

```
Meteor.publish("items", (limit,skip) => {
  return items.find({}, {limit: limit || 15,skip : skip});
})
```

There is no other alternative to calling `Meteor.subscribe` again and this is the recommended way.

Comment: Sorry i should have clarified more, ill update above